# Aspect ratio constraint is not working for UIStackview with nested UIstackviews

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview, aspect-ratio

I have a view controller with six buttons.
I want to show them in 3 rows and 2 columns.
I decided to put each column of buttons (3 buttons) in a stack view and put 2 vertical stack views in 1 horizontal stack view.

I want my buttons to look square shaped.

I applied following constraints for the horizontal (main) stack view:

1. Align Center X to Safe Area
2. Align Center Y to Safe Area
3. Align leading to Safe Area Equals:50
4. Aspect Width:Aspect Height = 2:3

For some reason aspect ratio is not working and the width is still
larger than the height and more importantly the buttons are not square shaped.

I tried to update frames, to apply all possible alignment and distribution properties, however, it didn't solve the problem. Please check images below for your reference.

[View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzyy3.png)

[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNsfu.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide an image of the layout you actually want. 6 square buttons? Located where? The center of the main view? Why is autolayout needed? What changes on a bigger or smaller screen? Just draw what it is you want. Thanks.

Comment: in the attribute inspector tab of the stack view, we have an option (Distribution). you can set that as Fill equally and define other constraints like aspect ratio (1:1) for each button to be able to get the design you want.

Comment: Dear Hamid, thank you. Your advise with aspect ratio for each button solved the problem!

Comment: Dear Matt, thank you for your comment, Hamid already provided a solution.